# How do I /setblock signs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does anyone know how you can use **/setblock** to make a sign face what direction you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following command.

For standing signs:
`/setblock ~ ~ ~ standing_sign <0-15, each representing a direction.>`

For wall signs:
`/setblock ~ ~ ~ wall_sign <0-15, each representing a direction.>`

0=South, 4=West, 8=North, 12=East

With F3 you can see the rotation on the right side of the debug overlay. Please note that when you put two floating signs together, it will automatically fall off. The reason for this is because when you place the sign on another it automatically updates the first sign causing it to pop off because off no block support then causing the second sign to fall from the first signs update.

Comment: For some reason if I want to have a sign on a block facing west, but I can't find the number for it do you happen to know what it is?

Comment: It will be 4 for facing west.

Comment: 3 faces south..

Comment: It it's I must of passed that. thanx

Comment: I believe, for the data values, 2=north, 3=south, 4=west, and 5=east (from [this](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Sign#Data_values) source).

Comment: Depends on whether it's a wall-mounted sign or a standing sign.